# Pass parameter to SharePoint Timer job

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How can I pass a parameter to a SharePoint Timer job?

btw, I am just a beginner to SharePoint.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I am moving documents from one site to another site according to external DB status.
So I want to pass those DB user name and password, SharePoint sites' names as parameter.
I don't wanna hardcode those.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [SPWorkItemJobDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spworkitemjobdefinition.aspx)

You can use `TextPayload` to pass parameters `(document url, fromSiteUrl, toSiteUrl etc.)`

It's like using a queue. Pass in some parameters from UI. `Timerjobs` processes queue, reads the payload and starts processing.

Answer (score 2):

When you write your timer job, you will override `Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)` method from the `SPJobDefinition`. Here you cannot unfortunately pass any parameters.

What you can do, is to store the values somewhere, where your timer job would be able to access them. One way, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637349/sharepoint-timer-job-and-log4net) mentions, would be to put that in a `.config` file inside of 14 Hive. Or some database table. Or `SPPropertyBag` in your `SPWeb`.

Answer (score 1):

you can store your userid and psw in config file i.e. OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG. you can find this file at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN.
if it is not their then you can create one. please make sure that file name must be in capital leters. below i have mentioned sample content of this config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
      <add key="USERID" value="testUser" />
      <add key="PSW" value="testPSW" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

if you are using C# then you can access these nodes using

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USERID"]
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PSW"]
```

Dont forget to reset your sharepoint timer service once you made changes in your config file.